# Selecting friends giving high rating each other SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table which contains four fields

```
1: cause
2: employee1
3: employee2
4: rating
```

Here employee2 is providing rating to employee1 on the specified cause.
I need to find out pair of employees who always gives rating 5 to each other.

I am new to sql and know basics of this language but I am not getting what to do in this situation.

Comment: sample data would help !!

Comment: have you tried anything????

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres? DB2?

Comment: what I know about sql that we can extract data based upon one row data like "where a='b'" but I don't think here that is going to be used, as we need to find data from multiple rows.

Comment: Thanks Mack, but the query is they should give rating 5 each time.
in this case they can give 3 or 2 some times.

Comment: @user3036327 see revision - now using MIN to avoid 2 or 3 scores..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/123a0/18)

--Test data setup:

```
CREATE TABLE #emptable (cause varchar(20), emp1 varchar(20), emp2 varchar(20), rating int)
INSERT INTO #emptable (cause, emp1, emp2, rating) VALUES('C1', 'emp A', 'emp B', 5)
INSERT INTO #emptable (cause, emp1, emp2, rating) VALUES('C1', 'emp B', 'emp A', 5)
--INSERT INTO #emptable (cause, emp1, emp2, rating) VALUES('C1', 'emp A', 'emp B', 3)
INSERT INTO #emptable (cause, emp1, emp2, rating) VALUES('C1', 'emp A', 'emp C', 5)
INSERT INTO #emptable (cause, emp1, emp2, rating) VALUES('C2', 'emp C', 'emp A', 2)
INSERT INTO #emptable (cause, emp1, emp2, rating) VALUES('C2', 'emp D', 'emp A', 3)
INSERT INTO #emptable (cause, emp1, emp2, rating) VALUES('C3', 'emp A', 'emp D', 5)
--INSERT INTO #emptable (cause, emp1, emp2, rating) VALUES('C1', 'emp B', 'emp A', 3)
```

--query

```
SELECT E1.emp1, E1.emp2
FROM #emptable E1
INNER JOIN #emptable E2
    ON E1.emp1 = E2.emp2
    AND E2.emp1 = E1.emp2
    AND E1.cause = E2.cause
GROUP BY E1.emp1, E1.emp2
HAVING MIN( E1.rating)=5
AND MIN(E2.rating)=5
DROP TABLE #emptable
```

--results

```
emp1    emp2
emp A   emp B
emp B   emp A
```

Comment: Thanks Mack, but the query is they should give rating 5 each time.
in this case they can give 3 or 2 some times.

Comment: Thanks I just needed to remove cause part as I wanted to have employee who help each other in any cause(also each cause is different in my case). Thanks a lot mack.

Comment: and I don't know how to mark you answer correct as I am new to stack overflow, please suggest.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT E1.* FROM SAMPLE AS E1, SAMPLE AS E2 WHERE 
E1.RATING = E2.RATING AND
E1.RATING=5 AND E2.RATING=5
AND E1.employee1 = E2.employee2
```

Comment: This does not filter out employees that have also given ratings other than 5.

Comment: you didnt asked to do so in your question. So plz be clear with your queries.

Comment: I'm not user3036327; and he said "always".